# Matching a value to a row, given 3 variables have the same value?

Tags: python, dataframe

Apologies for the confusion on the question. I wrote it out here, as I’m on mobile and it’s easier to draw out the dataframes. I’m given 2 df’s and I know that all players in each row will correspond to the same team, but I need something to automatically assign that team to the players’ row. Please don’t hard code the names in because there are thousands of rows and I’m given personal-id’s, not actual names.

[image: content and question]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most optimal solution but you can loop over each row and check that all players belong to a single team. Since you mention that you're given personal IDs, i am assuming they are unique, hence this method won't run into the problem of duplicates.
You retrieve the ID of first player in each row and find it's team.

```
i = 1
first_team = None
for row in playbyplay.iterrows():
    id = row['Player 1']
    if i == 1:
    first_team = linesups2.loc[lineups2['PlayerID'] == name]['TM']
    i += 1 # i is not important anymore
    flag = True
    for column in playbyplay.columns[1:]: # don't want to compare 'TM' column
        if linesups2.loc[lineups['PlayerID'] == row[column]['TM'] != first_team:
            flag = False
            break

    if flag == True:
        row['TM'] = first_name
```

I have quickly jotted this down so there may be some small errors but hopefully you get the logic of it.